# Table and query design options

Tags: mysql

We have a alert table which have deviceID as a foreign key. At present one alert just refers to one devive so things works smoothly with join. The problem start now when one alert now is to refer to more then one device. Thus we plan to keep a separate table with this alertID as foreign keys and devices ID in a new table say alertDetails. The issue now comes with this method is that there is no direct method to gain all the devices for a particular alert. Is there any solution or we have to run two separate queries where first one check if a particular type of alertCode(referring to more then one device) then run next query.

Comment: Use the [`JOIN`](http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqljoin.php), Luke!

Comment: What type of join works best here surely not normal join right

Comment: Do you mean "[natural join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_join#Natural_join)"?

Comment: Can you show some sample data and desired results, so we don't have to reverse engineer a word problem to attempt to help you solve your issue?

Answer (score 4):

While it is not exactly clear what you need but if you design your tables similar to below then you should be able to retrieve the details that you need.

```
create table alert
(
  id int,
  aname varchar(10)
);
create table device
(
  id int,
  dname varchar(10)
);
create table alertDetails
(
  alertId int,
  deviceId int,
  alertDate datetime
);
```

Then when you query, you could use the following:

```
select *
from alert a
left join alertdetails ad
  on a.Id = ad.alertid
left join device d
  on ad.deviceid = d.id
where a.id = 1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with a Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/46d0f/2)

Comment: I think is very close let me go through first and test and give you and update.

Comment: so I must specify the alertID which I require to look up the alertDetails table right. I guess then is best to run 2 separate queries right one specifically just for the particular alertID to check for the details?

Comment: @newbie14 if you take off the `WHERE` clause on the query, you will return all of the alert details for all alerts.

Comment: let me try out first and will update your accorddingly.